# Rails: Is my Ajax partial being rendered before the action is finished?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, partials

I have a User model, and each user has_many: Deliveries. I have a partial called _currentDeliveries, that shows a user some information about each of their Deliveries.


Each Delivery that is shown has a delete button next to it (which is just a little square div for now), and I'm using Ajax so if a user clicks the delete button next to one of their Deliveries, that delivery will be destroyed removed from the list (by re-rendering the partial) without refreshing the page. 


I have it almost working the way I want, the only problem is when I click the delete button for one Delivery, it is not removed from the list until I click the delete button of another delivery. And, the second delivery I delete is not removed from the list until I click a third delete button, and so on.

Basically, the partial is always one move behind where it should be, which makes me think the partial is being rendered before the Delivery is completely Deleted.


Here is the div that contains the partial:

```
<div id="currentDeliveriesArea">
        <%= render "currentDeliveries", user: @user %>
    </div>
```

Here is the partial:

```
<% user.deliveries.each do |d| %>
<div class="deliveryBox">
    <div class="deliveryBoxLeft">
        <div class="editDeliveryButton">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="deliveryBoxCenter">
        <p class="deliveryTitleText">Delivery</p>
        <p class="deliveryTimeText">
        <% if d.minute > 9 %>
            <% if d.am == 1 %>
                <%= d.hour %>:<%= d.minute %> am
            <% else %>
                <%= d.hour %>:<%= d.minute %> pm
            <%end%>
        <% else %>
            <% if d.am == 1 %>
                <%= d.hour %>:0<%= d.minute %> am
            <% else %>
                <%= d.hour %>:0<%= d.minute %> pm
            <%end%>
        <%end%>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="deliveryBoxRight">
        <div class="deleteDeliveryButton" onclick="getDeleteDelivery(<%= d.id %>);">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript function that is called when div "deleteDeliveryButton" is clicked:

```
function getDeleteDelivery(delivery){
$.get("/deleteDelivery", {delivery: delivery})}
```

Here is the deleteDelivery action in the users_controller:

```
def deleteDelivery
    @user = current_user
    puts "made it to delete action"
    @user.deliveries.each do |d|
        puts "Delivery ID " + d.id.to_s

    end
    @delivery = params[:delivery]
    puts "User deliveries count before: " + @user.deliveries.count.to_s
    Delivery.find(@delivery).destroy
    puts "User deliveries count after: " + @user.deliveries.count.to_s

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

Here is the deleteDelivery.js.erb file that gets called from the action and re-renders the partial:

```
$("#currentDeliveriesArea").html("<%= j(render partial: 'currentDeliveries', locals: {user: @user}) %>");
```

If I refresh the page after every delete button click, deliveries are removed from the list each time, but for some reason the Ajax seems to lag 1 click behind. The console says that the delivery is deleted completely, and @user.deliveries.count is one less, before it says the _currentDeliveries is rendered and then deleteDelivery.js.erb is rendered, so I'm not really sure what is going on. 

Sorry about the bad naming conventions btw!

Comment: What does that `puts` says on your server log? Does it change before and after?

Comment: Yes, it does change. It says, for example "User deliveries count before: 4", and "User deliveries count after: 3". Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: You mention using Ajax, so I searched for "remote", yet I didn't find it in your code.  Also, you are performing a `get` to delete a delivery - this is a big no no and a security risk.  HTTP Get should be [idempotent](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/).  To fix this, you should `post` with `remote:true`.